# async call to database for loop not wait

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm simply trying to access database while parsing json. This small block of code making my life hell

```
function loopColumns(val, cb){
    db.one('select tag_name from t_tag where tag_id = $1', val)
    .then(function (data) {
        //console.log(data.tag_name)
        cb(null, data.tag_name)
    });

}
```

var value = {"Travel Activity":[1,2], "Travel style":[3,4]};

```
for( i in value){ 
    //console.log(value[i], i)
    var output = '';
    var outcome = '';
    var str = value[i];
    for(j in str){
        loopColumns(str[j], function(err,res){
            if(outcome=='') outcome= res;
            else outcome= outcome+' , '+res;
            console.log(outcome);
        })

    }

    var output = i+' : '+outcome+' \n';
    console.log('output \n'+output);
};
```

this comes output 
output 
Travel Activity :
output 
Travel style :
good food 
good food , Hicking
good food , Hicking , xyz
good food , Hicking , xyz , test

> I like to get output as 
>   Travel style : good food, Hicking
>   Travel Activity : xyz , test

Plz save my life

Comment: Use `Promise`..

Comment: Remove duplicate declaration of `var output`

Comment: i'm already using promise, it's problem of async behavior

Comment: You are suppose to provide complete example... Incomplete code will not help the cause...

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`Promise.all`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> *The `Promise.all`(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved.*

Use `for-loop` instead of `for-in` loop to iterate `array`

```js
function loopColumns(val, cb) {
  db.one('select tag_name from t_tag where tag_id = $1', val)
    .then(function(data) {
      cb(null, data.tag_name)
    });
}
var value = {
  "Travel Activity": [1, 2],
  "Travel style": [3, 4]
};
for (var i in value) {
  var output = '';
  var promiseArr = [];
  for (var j = 0, len = value[i].length; j < len; j++) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
      loopColumns(value[i], function(err, res) {
        resolve(res);
      });
    });
    promiseArr.push(promise);
  }
  Promise.all(promiseArr).then(function(arr) {
    var op = arr.join(', ');
    output += i + ' : ' + op + ' \n';
    console.log('output \n' + output);
  });
}
```

Comment: @shivshankar — I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Comment: help me plz to access output variable outside for-in loop to export other module

Comment: @shivshankar – Your module function should have a `callback`

Answer (score 1):

Use `each` from `async` utility module instead of using `for` loop.